# Is there a faster way to discover stored broken links?

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I have a lot of links in my database and lots of them are broken.
Now I use this for cycle to get broken links:

```
$r = 0;
for($i=1;$i<10000;$i++){
$sqlt1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM links WHERE id = '".$i."'");
    while ($film = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlt1))
    {
        $id = $film['id'];
        $link = $film['filmlink'];
        $title = $film['filmtitle'];
        $source = $film['source'];
    }

$string = file_get_contents($link);
$array = array('not found', 'deleted', 'Has Been Removed', '%not be loaded%', '%create video code', 'Conversion stage:');

if($id == "")
{}
else{
if($string == "")
{
    $result = "bad";
    echo $id." <a href='$link' target='_balnk'>".$title."</a> ".$source." link ".$result."<br>";
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM links WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    $r++;
}
elseif (strposa($string, $array, 1)) {
    $result = "bad";
    echo $id." <a href='$link' target='_balnk'>".$title."</a> ".$source." link ".$result."<br>";
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM links WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    $r++;
}
else{
    $result = "good";
}
}
}
echo "All bad links: ".$r;
```

But this way is very slow and usually I get timeout error.
How can I analyse links faster?

Broken link sample: http://vidto.me/svib83bb3r7t.html

Answer (score 1):

The best will be **asynchronous** checks with using for example node.js
You'll have to write similar checks to this which you did in PHP, but in asynchronous way - you can connect node.js directly to your database

Or you can send every link status through for example PUT method to PHP server - but you'll 
 have to setup the API endpoint for page.com/link/{id} and process it.